# Identifying missing data in SQL tables with joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to identify the data missing in PRODUCT_CONVERSION table, in conjunction with the PRODUCT and the ORDER table.

As a rule, there has to be two lines available for each product, in the PRODUCT_CONVERSION table.
First one, with Product.BaseUoM as FROM_UOM and "ST" as TO_UOM (this is static).
Second one, with Product.BaseUoM as FROM_UOM and Order.OrderUoM as TO_UOM.

Here is the query I have used, but it doesnt seem to give the expected results. Can I get some support on what is not right with my query please? Thank you

```
select distinct P.PRODUCT,BASE_UOM,TXN_UOM,BASE_UOM_CODE,ALTERNATE_UOM_CODE,BASE_QUANTITY,ALTERNATE_QUANTITY
from ORDER T 
join PRODUCT P on P.PRODUCT=T.PRODUCT 
full outer join PRODUCT_CONVERSION PC on PC.PRODUCT_ID=T.PRODUCT
where 
PC.PRODUCT_ID is null
AND
(BASE_UOM<>TXN_UOM or BASE_UOM<>'ST') 
order by P.PRODUCT
```

Product
Product BaseUom
Product 1   EA

Order
PRODUCT OrderUOM
Product 1   ME1

Product Conversion
PRODUCT FROM UOM    TO UOM  BASE QTY    ALTERNATE QTY
Product 1   EA  ST  1   0.5
Product 1   EA  ME1 1   0.8     This line is expected, but lets assume is missing

Expected Result from joining all tables:
PRODUCT FROM UOM    TO UOM  TXN UOM BASE QTY    ALTERNATE QTY
Product 1   EA  ST  ME1 1   0.5
Product 1   EA  ME1 ME1 NULL    NULL    So I would expect in my result this line that shows this is missing

[image]

Comment: `full outer join` combined with `where PC.PRODUCT_ID is not null` is a contradiction.

Comment: @jarlh thanks for highlighting, i changed that earlier to test something, have corrected that now.

Comment: The lack of column qualifying and no sample data ([images don't count](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)) or expected results make this very difficult for us the be able to help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the left join to find the missing record.

```
SELECT a.MATERIAL, a.B_UOM, a.A_UOM, a.B_QTY, a.A_QTY
    FROM TABLE1 a
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b
        ON a.MATERIAL = b.MATERIAL
        AND a.B_UOM = b.B_UOM
        AND a.A_UOM = b.A_UOM
            WHERE b.MATERIAL IS NULL
```

use merger query to insert missing records.

```
MERGE TABLE3 AS TARGET
USING 
(SELECT a.MATERIAL, a.B_UOM, a.A_UOM, a.B_QTY, a.A_QTY
    FROM TABLE1 a
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b
        ON a.MATERIAL = b.MATERIAL
        AND a.B_UOM = b.B_UOM
        AND a.A_UOM = b.A_UOM
            WHERE b.MATERIAL IS NULL
) AS SOURCE
ON SOURCE.MATERIAL = TARGET.PRODUCT
AND SOURCE.B_UOM = TARGET.FROM_UOM
AND SOURCE.A_UOM = TARGET.TO_UOM
WHEN NOT MATCHED
   THEN
        INSERT (PRODUCT, FROM_UOM, TO_UOM,FROM_QUANTITY,TO_QUANTITY)
        VALUES (MATERIAL,B_UOM,A_UOM,B_QTY,A_QTY);
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer to use correlated subqueries to tackle this kind of problem.

The advantage for me is that I can easily compartmentalize different "conditions" to check for, and deal with the logic separately without actually having to worry about joins and the implications of expanding the rows, etc.

```
SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID
FROM PRODUCT P
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
  FROM PRODUCT_CONVERSION PC
  WHERE PC.TO_UOM = 'ST'
  AND P.BASEUOM = PC.FROM_UOM)
```

Now we can work add the 2nd condition as well,

```
SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID
FROM PRODUCT P
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
  FROM PRODUCT_CONVERSION PC
  WHERE PC.TO_UOM = 'ST'
  AND P.BASEUOM = PC.FROM_UOM)

OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
  ORDERS O ON P.PRODUCT_ID = O.PRODUCT_ID
  INNER JOIN PRODUCT_CONVERSION PC 
  ON PC.TO_UOM = 'ST'
  AND P.BASEUOM = PC.FROM_UOM)
)
```